# Simple OSX app without using storyboards

Tags: swift, macos, viewcontroller, appdelegate

I'm trying to learn Swift trough creating a simple OSX application. My sole purpose at this moment is to open a single window without using storyboards. My project contains 3 files right now. I didn't write most of it myself, I found it somewhere on the internet.

When running the project, there are no errors. The problem is that the window I created simply doesn't show up.

Here is my code:

AppDelegate.swift: (The printed message doesn't show up when running...)

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    let mainWindowController = MainWindowController()

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        print("app finished launching")
        mainWindowController.showWindow(self)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    }    
}
```

MainViewController.swift:

```
import Cocoa

class MainViewController: NSViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        let rightView = NSView(frame: NSRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 400, height: 400)))
        view = rightView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let rightView = NSView(frame: NSRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 400, height: 400)))
        view = rightView
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

MainWindowController.swift:

```
import Cocoa

class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {

    convenience init() {
        let MVC = MainViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.init(window: NSWindow(contentViewController: MVC!))
        window?.titleVisibility = .visible;
        let size = NSSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        window?.setContentSize(size)

        window?.title = "*Random text*"
        window?.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
        window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = false
    }

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Anybody got any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong here? Any help would be deeply appreciated!!